# Disminuir el alto de la cabecera de un tema en WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

He tratado de disminuir el alto de la cabecera de este sitio web: [ishameetings.cl](http://ishameetings.cl/) sin éxito.

Además la plantilla de WordPress que estoy personalizado es [Albar.](https://wordpress.org/themes/albar/)

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: Suponiendo que quieres disminuirlo a `80px` (actualmente está en `110px`), primero debes reducirle el alto al envoltorio del menú: `.site-header-one .site-header-right { height: 80px; }` y luego, a los anchor dentro del menú reducirle el padding: `.site-header-one.header-nosocial .navigation-main a { padding: 5px 8px 8px; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Debe disminuir primero los divs contenedores internos dentro de  ya que los internos impiden que el externo redusca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En la plantilla [Albar](https://wordpress.org/themes/albar/) debes modificar el id **wporg-header**

```
#wporg-header {
    height: 120px;
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

por ejemplo:

```
#wporg-header {
    height: 180px;  // <-
    text-align: inherit;
}
```